# how to send visual studio project 2017 to github?

Tags: visual-studio, github

I have a project already connected to visual studio team services, because it is already connected there is no option to connect to a new git repository.

Does anyone know how to send the source code to GitHub through visual studio when this is the case?

When I go to the file menu there is nothing saying "add to source control".
Or in the bottom right button, there is only a `master` button which has something about branches.
I don't understand why they make it so hard by redefining so many things like download to pull and upload to push.
Can someone tell me that answer as well?

Comment: You don't need Visual Studio to send projects to GitHub. Use any Git client (including the command line) is enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easier to switch to command line and check if your local sources are themselves in a Git repo:

```
cd /path/to/local/project
git status
git remote -v
```

If those commands fails, that means your project is connected to visual studio team services through TFVC, and not Git, in which case, you need to create a local Git repo (which will co-exists with the TFVC one)

```
git init .
git add .
git commit -m "first commit"
```

Eve if the Git repo already existed, you can continue with:

```
git remote add github /url/empty/GitHub/repo
git push --mirror
```